# Set doctrine entity boolean field to 0 instead of null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im trying to persist an doctrine entity with a boolean field where the values are 0 or 1.

When the property is set to true, it save it as '1' in database.
But when its 'false' or '0', it save it as NULL on database.

How can I fix this to only save only as 1 or 0 ?

The annotation for the property I use is like following:

```
@ORM\Column(name="substitute", type="boolean", nullable=true)
```

When I set nullable to false, I cant persist it because it still want to set to null.

Thanks

When I persist it, the field value is 0

**Attempt 1**
@ORM\Column(name="substitute", type="boolean", options={"default":"0"}))

*error: Can't save null*

**Attempt 2**
@ORM\Column(name="substitute", type="boolean", nullable= true, options={"default":"0"}))

*Doesn"t work, it still save null in base*

**Info 1**

*The actually insert query is trying to insert 0. But I got this error "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (\"MYBASE\".\"MYTABLE\".\"SUBSTITUTE\")"*

**Info 2**

Same append with another entity

```
class TestEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="test_entity_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="substitute", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isSubstitute = false;
}
```

Persisting

```
$test = new TestEntity();
$test->setIsSubstitute(false);
$em->persist($test);
```

Result

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO TestEntity (test_entity_id, substitute) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [7, 0]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1400 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYBASE"."TESTENTITY"."SUBSTITUTE")  (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)"\n (ext\\pdo_oci\\oci_statement.c:148) at PATH\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOStatement.php:91)"} []
```

**Info 3**

*Inserting manually works using oci or oci8 driver*

```
sql> INSERT INTO TestEntity (test_entity_id, substitute) VALUES (13, 0)
[2017-04-06 11:21:15] 1 row affected in 62ms
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the default: 0 stuff is strictly for the database.  Doctrine itself does not set any defaults in your entity.  private $substitute = false; should work.  If it does not then you have something else changing the value.

Comment: When debugging the line $em->persist($affectation), the field value is correctly set to 'false'. The actually insert query replaced the 'false' to '0', But i get the error "cannot insert NULL"...

Comment: Sounds like either a configuration issue or a controller issue. Is your Oracle connection working properly for other Entities? I presume you've setup oci8 correctly?

Comment: @AlvinBunk im using the oci driver. (not the oci8). I dont have other entities with this case.

Comment: If you are using Symfony with Oracle you should be using oci8. Your parameters.yml file should have: `database_driver: oci8` I created an article about [installing OCI8 on RHEL](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/installing-oci8-on-rhel/) if you need help. Basically according to Oracle and the Underground PHP and Oracle Manual, you should be using oci8 with PHP.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I read your article, that's interresting. I'll first use this if I really can't fix in other way.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I changed my doctrine dbal driver from pdo_oci to oci8. And it works. Thanks a lot. Could you create an answer to allow me to mark as resolved ?

Comment: I added a second answer. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your driver from `oci` to `oci8` in your paramters.yml file:

```
database_driver: oci8
```

That should do it. Use [the Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) for installing OCI8.

Answer (score 23):

Just set the SQL Default to 0 (**Edit: You need to update the schema after that change**):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":"0"})
 */
protected $isActive;
```

Also you could initialize the property by default:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":"0"})
 */
protected $isActive = false;
```

Nullable shouldn't matter as long as the value is set to either true/false.

If you really set the property to false before saving and it still saves it as null in the DB then something else is going on.

Comment: Thank, for your answer. I'll try it and tell you if it work in a moment.

Comment: I still get an error after changing the annotation (and updating the schema) @ORM\Column(name="substitute", type="boolean", options={"default":"0"})). He is trying to set null on a non nullable field.
I'll try to set nullable=true

Comment: That's really strange. Do you have a debugger running? If so you should check if the property really is set to true or false right before it's written to the database. Also you could take a look at the sfToolbar and search for the actual query that got executed against the DB to check which values were passed from the object

Comment: have you really updated your schema and cleared your cache?

Comment: I didnt cleared my cache, just updated the schema and checked that the field property on database is actuelly changed.

Comment: The actually insert query is trying to insert 0. But I got this error "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (\"MYBASE\".\"MYTABLE\".\"SUBSTITUTE\")"... Very strange behavior

Answer (score 2):

I think @Cerad's suggestion is correct, can you try:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="substitute", type="boolean")
 */
protected $substitute = false;
```

Let us know the result.

Comment: I did it too. Doesn't work. As *I said on the comment: The actually insert query is trying to insert 0. But I got this error "ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (\"MYBASE\".\"MYTABLE\".\"SUBSTITUTE\")"... Very strange behavior

Comment: Maybe try connecting to the database via a console window and manually running a simple INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 1):

I just replicated your case, and I managed to successfully save into the db 1 for true, and 0 for false.

Example:

```
//Entity
Person: id, name, isMajor(boolean field)
//IMPORTANT: I setted the boolean field inside __construct() method, and let it be, by default, false (0). This means you don't need anymore to have that options={"default":"0"}.

//...
/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isMajor", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isMajor;

public function __construct() 
{
    $this->isMajor = false;
}

//Created CRUD against the Entity

//When saving (either using the default actions provided by the CRUD, or by setting the values inside another controller's action):
//AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
/**
 * @Route("/new-person")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $person = new Person();
    $person->setName('name');
    $person->setIsMajor(true); // this saves 1 in the table
    $person->setIsMajor(false); // this saves 0 in the table

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($person);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('person_index');
}
```

I hope I did understood well your problem.

Comment: Do you use an oracle database with pdo_oci driver ?

Comment: @fliim Oh, sorry, this example is using the old good mysql as RDBM.

Answer (score 0):

You can create fake object using `$em->getReference(EntityName::class, "AnyValue");`

Happy coding.

Comment: Cab you explain that further? Why is such a "fake object" needed?